# How can I export a comma-separated list of values from a column of an org-mode table

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a table in org-mode with emails in one column. I want to collect all the emails as a comma-separated list, but I don't know an easy way to do it. It seems like something fairly simple, but I can't find a solution anywhere on the web.

What would be the simplest way to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for a repeatable automated solution, or just a series of manual steps?

Comment: Do you only want the column with the emails in a csv?  Or do you want the entire content of the table (one email per line with whatever other data as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dipping my toes slightly into org mode, a very simple formula of `@1..` will do the trick of making a list from the values in the current column from rows 1 onwards, as it simply joins the values by commas by default. e.g.:

```
#+TBLFM: @5$2=@1..
```

(followed by <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> to evaluate), would create a list in row 5, column 2, of all the values in column 2.

It does wrap the list in square brackets, but that's obviously no problem for a manual approach.

Answer (score 2):

One manual approach would be to use rectangle editing commands to extract the content of that column (which should be nicely aligned by org-mode), and then just search and replace to convert to CSV format:

- <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> at first corner
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> at opposite corner
- <kbd>C-/</kbd> to undo the kill (there's no default copy-rectangle command)

Then in the buffer where you want the list of addresses:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to yank the rectangle
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd> to exchange point and mark, marking the region
- <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> to regex search and replace within the region, like so:

<kbd>C-M-%</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Does M-x org-table-export do what you want?